# Uncertainty on the standard deviation of data set, when the data points are uncertain

Tags: dataset, standard-deviation, error, uncertainty

I have a set of four data points (x,y), and I would like to describe the spread of the data about the mean in both the x-direction and in the y-direction. Each individual data point has an uncertainty associated with it, which would make the mean have an uncertainty (I think). From here, I can calculate the standard deviation of these four data points about the mean, but I have no idea what the uncertainty associated with this standard deviation calculation would be. Could someone help me understand this?

I normally don't think of the standard deviation as having any uncertainty, but I could most definitely be wrong.

Comment: Can you say a bit more about how the uncertainty in the data points was measured?